# Django - Error al mostrar dato en template {{ station.producto }}

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Template me saca número 0 y 1 pero no saca la palabra Piezas o Utensilios. ¿Qué ocurre?

```
AREA_CHOICE = (
    ('0','Piezas'),
    ('1','Utensilios'),
)
area = models.CharField('Area', max_length=1, choices=AREA_CHOICE,null=True)
```

Al sacar en template me muestra 0 ó 1, pero no el segundo campo Piezas o Utensilios:

```
<h1>{{ station.area }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer no sabes como funciona [`Field.choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices), la documentación de Django de como funciona:

> *El primer elemento en cada tupla es el **valor real que se establecerá
>   en el modelo**, y el segundo elemento es el nombre **legible por humanos**.
>   Por ejemplo:*
>
> ```
> YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
>     ('FR', 'Freshman'),
>     ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
>     ('JR', 'Junior'),
>     ('SR', 'Senior'),
>     ('GR', 'Graduate'),
> ]
> ```
>
> ...

Es por eso que al mostrar el valor del campo `area` en tu template ( `{{ station.area }}` ) muestra `1` o `0`, pues son los valores que se establecen en el modelo, según tus `choices`.

Pero, para cada campo, que haya un `choices`, el objeto o la instancia tendrá un método [`get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display), donde `FOO` es el nombre del campo. Este método devuelve el valor "legible para humanos" del campo.

Es decir si quieres obtener el valor "legible para humanos" del campo `area` en tu template, seria así:

```
<h1>{{ station.get_area_display }}</h1>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Así es. Funciona perfecto. Gracias Julio Cesar.

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte! :)