# Obtener etiqueta del campo choices en la vista de django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Tengo un modelo donde uno de los campos tiene un campo choices que sirve para definirle un color.

```
class Gateway(models.Model):
    colors = (
        ('0','Black'), ('1','White'), ('2','Blue'), ('3','Red'),
        ('4','Green'), ('5','Brown'), ('6','Grey'), ('7','Pink'),
        ('8','Purple'), ('9','Orange'), ('10','Yellow'),('11','Darkolive'),
        ('12','Lightpink'),('13','Lightblue'),
    )

    gat_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    gat_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    gat_lat = models.FloatField()
    gat_lon = models.FloatField()
    gat_color = models.IntegerField(choices=colors, default=0)
```

Cuando obtengo la información de este modelo desde mi vista hago lo siguiente,

```
gateways = Gateway.objects.all()
```

El problema es que este me devuelve en el campo `gat_color` el identificador numérico y yo querría que me diera la etiqueta del color. ¿Es esto posible?

**Aclaración:**

Estos datos no van a salir al template, se quedarán en el back para llevar a cabo una serie de operaciones y como mucho llegarían al template desde una llamada javascript y ajax.

Si yo hago `gateways = Gateway.objects.all()` y luego serializo `gateways` ya tengo esta posibilidad pues se me genera un diccionario/json y de aquí hago todas las operaciones pertinentes. El problema es en la etiqueta de color, que me da el código y no la palabra y para mi proyecto es más interesante conocerla.

**---**

No pongo código porque la verdad no sé como afrontar el problema y no encuentro la información donde se explique.

Muchas gracias y un saludo!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Django - Error al mostrar dato en template {{ station.producto }}](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/349176/django-error-al-mostrar-dato-en-template-station-producto)

Comment: No. Eso sirve para trabajar un templateview o similar yo quiero el resultado como dije para luego serializarlo con JSON

Comment: Podrías hacer lo siguiente: `{'gat_color': instance.get_gat_color_display()}` y serializarlo a JSON, dicho método no estrictamente tiene que funcionar en vistas o en templates.

Comment: mmm perdona pero no entiendo la propuesta que me haces, ¿esto lo haría en la vista? He editado el post para intentar aclarar mis intenciones :)

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 1):

Los identificadores, números o "código" como lo dices **son el valor real que se establecerá en el modelo**, es decir:

> *El primer elemento en cada tupla es el valor real que se establecerá en el modelo, y el segundo elemento es el **nombre legible por humanos**.*

Y para cada campo, que haya un `choices`, el objeto o la instancia tendrá un método `get_FOO_display()`, donde `FOO` es el nombre del campo. Este método devuelve el valor "legible para humanos" del campo.

Es decir el nombre del método es: `get_gat_color_display()`

Todo esto se explica con mas detalles [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/349176/django-error-al-mostrar-dato-en-template-station-producto).

---

Por otra parte, algo que no me cuadraba era que el valor que se establecerá en el modelo era de tipo `str` (los primeros elementos de cada tupla del choices `colors`) y no de tipo `int` ya que el campo `gat_color` es un campo `IntegerField`, debido a esto cree un proyecto y replique el problema para ver si eso daba error, pero al parecer no es así, Django transforma a `int` el valor del campo `gat_color` si es posible antes de crear la instancia, y como `'1'` o `'2'`, etc, pueden transformarse a tipo de dato `int`, pues no hay problema y no sucede ningún error.

Pero solo se pueden crear las instancias por métodos (`save()` o `create()`) ya que el admin no te deja crear instancias del modelo, debido al choices `colors`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y debido a esto hay otro problema que evitara solucionar el problema "principal", y es que al parecer el método `get_gat_color_display()` no funciona y solo devuelve el "código" o el valor establecido en el modelo, lo mas lógico es que esto se debe a que el choices `colors`, tiene como primer elemento en cada tupla el código o numero de tipo `str`.

Entonces hay que solucionar esto primero, antes de solucionar el problema principal. Habría que cambiar el campo `gat_color` a un campo `CharField` o cambiar todos los primeros elementos de cada tupla en el choices `colors`, a enteros y no a cadena, y que daría tal que así:

```
colors = (
    (0,'Black'), (1,'White'), (2,'Blue'), (3,'Red'),
    (4,'Green'), (5,'Brown'), (6,'Grey'), (7,'Pink'),
    (8,'Purple'), (9,'Orange'), (1,'Yellow'),(1,'Darkolive'),
    (1,'Lightpink'),(1,'Lightblue'),
)
```

Una ves solucionado esto, podemos solucionar el problema principal que es:

> *El problema es en la etiqueta de color, que me da el código y no la
>   palabra y para mi proyecto es más interesante conocerla.*

Como lo mencione antes, esto se debe a que el primer elemento en cada tupla es el valor real que se establecerá en el modelo, y para solucionarlo seria de la siguiente manera:

```
def view(request):

    # Obtenermos la instancia por el metodo filter(), para asi obtener un diccionario
    # en ves de una instancia, mas despues
    queryset = Gateway.objects.filter(pk=1)

    # Obtenermos la instancia pero en diccionario
    dict_instance = queryset.values()[0]

    # Actualisamos la key "gat_color" con la "palabra" o el color
    dict_instance['gat_color'] = queryset[0].get_gat_color_display()

    # Retornamos el dicionario ya serialisado a JSON
    return JsonResponse(dict_instance)
```

Y listo, obtienes la instancia ya serializada a JSON con el valor deseado en cuanto al campo `gat_color`, espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Yo estoy siempre lo resuelvo así:

```
from enum import IntEnum

def choiceadapter(enumtype):
    return ((item.value, item.name.replace('_', ' ')) for item in enumtype)

class Colors(IntEnum):
        black = 0
        white = 1
        # ...
        lightblue = 13
```

Y después en el modelo le digo:

```
class Gateway(models.Model):
    # ...
    gat_color = models.IntegerField(
                   choices=choiceadapter(Colors),
                   default=Colors.black.value
                )
```

Esto te permite tener los elementos más claramente definidos y el `choiceadapter()` te lo mapea para que puedas seleccionar.